# Why did Pete say, "You're thinking of fourth grade"?

Tags: dreamcatcher

Beaver tells to Pete about his sex at other night:

> Beaver: Though I've had perfectly good fuckarees turn into  fuckarows
>   in a flash.
>
> Pete: Try Viagra.
>
> Beaver: Viagra? I'm practically at full salute all day. I'm....  What
>   do you call it? Privatic? Prag... Prasmatic? Henry will know.
>
> Pete: **You're thinking of fourth grade**.

It is from *Dreamcatcher (2003)* science fiction movie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your confusion probably stems from the fact that;

- The line is a bit mumbled (there's a fair amount of background noise from the cooking)

and

- The online transcript that you're using (presumably the one at [Springfield, Springfield](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=dreamcatcher)) actually has the line wrong.

The line should read;

> *"You're remembering yourself in the fourth grade."*

The implication is that when he was in the fourth grade (in early puberty) that erections arrived with unwelcome regularity, but that now that he's in his thirties, that that may no longer be the case.

Listening to the stories of how his last few sexual conquests fell flat, Pete suggests that Beaver should try viagra **and admit to himself that he's getting older.**

Comment: Aren't fourth graders 9 year olds? Are 9 year olds that horny nowadays? I';d have thought sixth or seventh grade would be more typical.

Comment: @user14111  - Yeah. It seems like a very awkward joke, frankly. The meaning is clear but the wording is weird.